# make https post request

Tags: java, xml, https

I am making an http post request to one of the xml gateways, but as per their rule I must post https post request, here is my code and i am getting a custom error code which indicates in their manual that the post request must be https, can you help me modifying the following code.

```
public class PostXML {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Get target URL
        String strURL = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/xmlgw/Gateway" ;

        // Get file to be posted
        String strXMLFilename = "F:\\12-8\\CompanyFormation\\CompanyFormation\\web\\file.xml";
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);

        // Prepare HTTP post
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

        // Request content will be retrieved directly
        // from the input stream
        // Per default, the request content needs to be buffered
        // in order to determine its length.
        // Request body buffering can be avoided when
        // content length is explicitly specified
        post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));

        // Specify content type and encoding
        // If content encoding is not explicitly specified
        // ISO-8859-1 is assumed
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        // Get HTTP client
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

        // Execute request
        try {
            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

            // Display status code
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);

            // Display response
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            // Release current connection to the connection pool 
            // once you are done
            post.releaseConnection();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, your question is how to change the request to `https`? Just change your `strURL` to start with `https://`...

Comment: hi shivan! i tried to change http to https, now it doesn't give any output, it just running and running. can you suggest something?

Comment: How can I know without further information? You should also contact the API provider as well.

Comment: have you ever worked with company house of UK xml gateway?

Comment: did you hit companies house XML gateway successfully?

Comment: yes alpesh but i am having some problem in the response, is there any way to communicate with you directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are implementing the HttpClient you will need to add make sure that you can get signed certificates from the server.

see http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html and maybe the Customizing SSL in HttpClient section.

As a validation check make sure that access is OK via a browser first.

Comment: but the XML Gateway site is not an authorized site, so how can i validate them?